# Meaning and grammar of '..., as if it had cause to sigh over ...'

Tags: meaning, grammar

I am confused by the following part of a sentence:

> '..., as if it had cause to sigh over ...'

Firstly, I am not sure what it means if written like that. Supposedly it says

> ..., as if it sighed over ...

I wonder what is the reason of having *cause* here. What kind of mood it suggests? What should I think if somebody says it like that?

Secondly, I don't understand what grammar construction this is. Does it even express a past tense? I would understand if there would be something like *had caused to* or *had a cause to*, but not *had cause to*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "cause" means "reason". So this means that it's as if it had a reason why it would sigh over something. This construct emphasizes the situation that "it" could be in, which would cause a sigh, rather than the act of sighing.

Comment: But shouldn't there be an article before a noun "cause" then?

Comment: No, idiomatically we don't use an article before this use of "cause".

Comment: Thanks, this was a major point of confusion for me. Is there some rule I can refer to why there isn't an article?

Comment: Not that I know of, idioms aren't governed by rules.